# Keep the height of a text even if it is a white space

Tags: html, css

There is a value like this:

```
<span className="my-value">{value}</span>
```

css:

```
  .my-value {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 22px;
    color: #0D1E2C;
  }
```

Value contains a text value which can be a string `"example"`. But it can also be this `" "`, a white space, case in which the element is not shown, on the page it looks like it does not exist.

I want to keep it there so the page is well structured.

I thought that `line-height` will keep it but it doesn't. Any ideas?

Comment: To me, i believe it's not possible to have a default height to an inline element, you can use block level element instead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an empty whitespace on a pseudo element to keep the space even if the text is empty.

```css
.my-value {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #0D1E2C;
}
.my-value::after {
  content:" ";
  font-size:0;
  white-space:pre;
}
```

```html
<span class="my-value"> </span>

<p>aaa</p>
```

Comment: it does not seem to work. how can I get that special white space?

Comment: that's how I've tried but didn't work. I'm using scss file and I added `&-value {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 22px;
    color: #0d1e2c;
    &::after {
      content: ' ';
    }
  }` and in the code it is: ` value: product.category ? product.category : ' '`

Comment: @LeoMessi did you copy the whitespace from my CSS Code or added your own?

Comment: I copied the one from your answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of `:empty` and `:after` to add a unicode character `\200b` which is a non-breaking space with zero-width to preserve the height of the span even if it's empty. So in your CSS, you will have:

```css
.my-value {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #0d1e2c;
}
.my-value:empty:after {
   content: '\200b';
}
```

The above code is clean in the sense that it will only add the character when the `span` element with the class on `my-value` is empty.

Comment: @LeoMessi is it possible to get a screenshot of your outcome?

Comment: I think that it should be with `:after` and `white-space:pre` as it was in @Temani Afif's answer which worked

Comment: I just performed another test and in both case, they both work. Tested with a p element as sibling of the span element.

Answer (score 1):

Your empty space will be ignored by the browser because it automatically formats spaces and newlines. You can replace your space by a `&nbsp;`

Comment: I'm doing it using ternary like this: `value: product.category ? product.category: ' ',`, is it a way to replace `' '` with `&nbsp;`?

Comment: No, space is not empty and evalutes to `true`. You have to to `product.category.replace(/\s+/g, "") ? product.category : "&nbsp;"`

Comment: Then you have a typo. Ive tested the code and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can try with using min-height or height attribute with the value that you want and display attribute with value inline-block or block.
It should be work

Answer (score 0):

CSS has a property called [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) which can be used to control this behaviour.

```css
.my-value {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Live demo:

```css
.my-value {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
This box has only white space: <span class="my-value"> </span>
```